# Android TextView setText does not work

Tags: android, textview, settext

I read some problems from other users facing the same problem, but the solutions didn't work for me.
I have defined a `TextView` in my layout `xml`:

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/currentLocation"
  android:layout_column="0"
  android:layout_row="14"
  android:text="@string/currentLocation" />
```

Now in my Activity I get the TextView by

```
location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentLocation);
```

In my activity I'm also able to start two other activities (one is a googlemap-View, the other one is the contactlist of the phone). My `onActivityResult()` method in the main activity looks like the following:

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT) :
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    try{
                        String address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS));
                        convertAddressToLatLon(address);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        errorDialog.setMessage("Could not get Address. Try another contact or use Google Maps.");
                        errorDialog.show();
                    }

                }
            }
        case (PICK_GMAPS) :
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle googleData = data.getExtras();
                location.setText(googleData.getString("address"));
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

In the `convertAddressToLatLon(address)` method there is also a `location.setText();` with definatelly a stringvalue!

So if i return from the `googlemap-activity`, location-text changes to given input. In the contactactivity part it does not work. But there is no error. It reaches the `location.setText()` method, but does not change the text. I have no idea whats wrong. its not possible, that there is a wrong character in the string. Even if I put 'location.setText("test")' after the closing braket of the catch block, it does not work. (again, the program goes into the `if(c.moveToFirst()){` part!). I have no idea whats wrong, because like I said the googlepart works correct.

Comment: where are the layout_width and height params for your textView?

Comment: @JimPanse Why are you not setting height and width of textview?

Comment: Did you try logging the value?

Comment: TextView contains android:layout_width="match_parent" and android:layout_height="wrap_content", but for my problem i dont think its necessary, because like i said, it is working.

Comment: @ ape: i logged everything. It reaches the setText() part, moves on to code below this part, but nothing happens to the textview. The strange thing is, that there is no real difference between the contact and the googlemaps-part. Also if i put the location.setText("test") directly below the "if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)", nothing happens. But in the googlemaps-part everything works fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the mistake. I forgot to put a "break;" at the end of the PICK_CONTACT-case. Now its working...

Answer (score 1):

At least set the height and width of your `TextView`.
Sth like:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

I think these are the basic parameters. Then you can seek for other reasons (if error continues).

Comment: Even if i forgot these parameters, the googlemaps-part works, the contact-part doesn't...